# F# Understanding Recursion Function

Tags: math, recursion, f#

I am trying to understand why a recursion function is behaving the way it is.

```
let rec fact = function 
   |0 -> 1
   |n -> n * fact(n-1);;
```

When i execute:

```
fact 4;;
```

it responds:

```
val it : int = 24
```

which is ofcourse Is correct since 1*2*3*4 = 24

What i don't get is this piece of code:

```
|n -> n * fact(n-1);;
```

I don't get why It doesn't calculate:

```
4 -> 4 * (4-1)
4 -> 4 * 3
4 -> 12
```

My guess Is I am misunderstanding the definition of n

can someone do the honor and enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not calculating `4 * (4-1)` because the code isn't `n * (n-1)`. It's `n * fact (n-1)`, so it calculates `4 * fact (4 - 1)`, which is:

```
  4 * fact (4 - 1)
= 4 * fact 3
= 4 * (function | 0 -> 1 | n -> n * fact (n-1)) 3
= 4 * (match 3 with | 0 -> 1 | n -> n * fact (n-1))
= 4 * 3 * fact (3 - 1)
= 4 * 3 * fact 2
...
```

And so on until you finally get `4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * fact 0 = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1 = 24`.

Comment: I am having difficulties figuring out what is happening at the point  you say "Match 3 with..." can you elaborate that a bit?

Comment: @Nulle `function | 0 -> 1 | n -> n * fact (n-1)` is a shortcut for writing `fun x -> match x with | 0 -> 1 | n -> n * fact (n-1)`. And if we apply that function to the argument `3`, we get `match 3 with | 0 -> 1 | n -> n * fact (n-1)`.

Answer (score 6):

That would be  true if the definition were `n -> n * (n - 1)` but it is making a recursive call to `fact` so it is:

```
4 * fact(4 - 1)
=> 4 * fact(3)
=> 4 * (3 * fact(2))
=> 4 * (3 * (2 * fact(1)))
=> 4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * fact(0))))
=> 4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * 1)))
=> 4 * (3 * (2 * 1))
=> 4 * (3 * 2)
=> 4 * 6
=> 24
```

Comment: I take it rec is what is making my function recursive so why is it when i remove rec from my code that I am still getting the same result? Everything you say makes sense by the way.

Comment: @Nulle - It's the call to `fact` from within the `fact` function that makes it recursive. F# requires recursive functions be declared with `rec` to make the function name visible inside the declaring function. If you just remove the `rec` keyword you should get a compilation error saying there is no definition for `fact`.

Comment: @Nulle `rec` is what *allows* your function to be recursive. If you remove it, you should get an error unless there's a previous definition of `fact`.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it now!

```
fact 4;; 
fun 4 match 4 with |0 -> 1|n -> n * fact(n-1)
|0 -> 1|4 -> 4 * fact(4-1)
|false |4 -> 4 * fact(3)
|false |4 -> 4 * fun 3 match 3 with |0 -> 1|n -> n * fact(n-1)
|false |4 -> 4 * |0 -> 1|3 -> 3 * fact(3-1)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * fact(2)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * fun 2 match 2 with |0 -> 1|n -> n * fact(n-1)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * |0 -> 1|2 -> 2 * fact(2-1)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * |false |2 -> 2 * fact(1)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * |false |2 -> 2 * fun 1 match 1 with |0 -> 1|n -> n * fact(n-1)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * |false |2 -> 2 * |0 -> 1|1 -> 1 * fact(1-1)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * |false |2 -> 2 * |false |1 -> 1 * fact(0)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * |false |2 -> 2 * |false |1 -> 1 * fun 0 match 0 with |0 -> 1|n -> n * fact(n-1)
|false |4 -> 4 * |false |3 -> 3 * |false |2 -> 2 * |false |1 -> 1 * |true|
4 -> 4 * 3 -> 3 * 2 -> 2 * 1 -> 1 * 0 -> 1 = 24
```